# PAM accepting any current password when changing LDAP password

Tags: centos, authentication, openldap, password, pam

I have a Centos-7.6 system, using PAM to authenticate LDAP users.
I've managed to force an LDAP user to change their password, by setting shadowLastChange to 0, so their password must be changed.

But if I su - as that user, or log in at the greeter, it will accept any password at the "current (UNIX) password: prompt". Of course, this prompt comes *after* already having typed in the user password, which is natural when using su or the greeter.

```
Password: 
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
need a new password
Changing password for test_user.
(current) UNIX password: <--------- anything you type here will be accepted
New password:
```

If using ssh test_user@centos7server, I'm still forced to change the password, but in this case, the password is checked properly, and bad passwords are not allowed.

```
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
need a new password
Last login: Tue Sep  3 15:42:36 2019
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user test_user.
Changing password for test_user.
(current) UNIX password: <---------- password is properly verified
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

NOTE: using similar settings on a Centos-6.10 system did not allow bad password, so it works properly.

Here is my /etc/pam.d setup on the Centos-7 machine:

/etc/pam.d/system-auth:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access.netgroup.conf
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nis nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

/etc/pam.d/password-auth is identical to system-auth (above)

/etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
auth     required pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
account required pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access.netgroup.conf
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

/etc/pam.d/login:

```
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

/etc/pam.d/su:

```
auth     sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth    sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth    required pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth     substack system-auth
auth     include     postlogin
account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account     include     system-auth
password include     system-auth
session     include     system-auth
session     include     postlogin
session     optional pam_xauth.so
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you are using this parameter in the password session: use_authtok
    This causes the PAM module to use the earlier provided password when changing the password. The module will not prompt the user for a new password (it is analogous to use_first_pass). you can configure the ldap using authconfig-tui command

Comment: the output I get proves this wrong. I'm prompted yet again for the current password. And the same thing happens when changing it to "use_first_pass"

Comment: why you don't use authconfig-tui to configure the ldap auth?